# Angular 8 two areas with other templates

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

How I can to use 2 other templates for my WEB?

I have Admin Area and Public Area, so for Admin I want to use - Dashboard Layout ( for example ) and it's should have access only for logged users, and Landing Page Layour for Public Area ( for all users ).

I just can't find solution in google

Can you, please, show architecure for project like this or take me some recommendations?

Comment: create  3 modules , app module ( also known as root module ) , then a Admin module  and  Public  module . The admin and  Public module should be  loaded to app module lazy loading will be preferred . and in each of this child modules create a main component which   will act as  master component into which other child  components can be loaded

Comment: You can use either different entry point for each scenario(kind like of 2 applications with shared code) or use router-outlet herarchy - root will display UserApplicationComponent or AdminApplicationComponent, and those components would have child router-outlets respectively.

Comment: I would recommend you study https://nx.dev/ as it is a solid base for starting, Meanwhile, please add so me code to you question, ask about errors or problems you are facing. Otherwise you will not get meaningful help...

Comment: good way - try to use routing (component - your layout, and canActivate - your guard for check auth & admin), but this isn't good for 2 different layouts for one route. Bad way - using *ngIf in your main layout template

Comment: @JoelJoseph Well thank you! But how I can apply styles for other layout? 
For example... For Admin I want to use styles-admin.scss and for Public - styles-public.scss